# REST request on Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I'm writing my first Android app where the first thing to do is collect a list of maps from a server, but I'm having difficulty getting a simple REST request working.  I've been following a number of tutorials and am trying to employ both AsyncTask and HttpURLConnection to do this properly.

For my simple initial test, I just call `getMapsJson`, with `serverUrl` set to "http://httpbin.org/ip" (just to make sure it's sending and receiving data correctly).

**Code**

```
public String getMapsJson()
{
    Log.d(Globals.tag, ">> getting maps json from " + serverUrl.toString());
    String output = "";

    new GetMapsJsonTask().execute(serverUrl);

    return output;
}

private class GetMapsJsonTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String>
{
    private HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    protected String doInBackground(URL... url)
    {
        String output = "";

        try
        {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url[0].openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            Log.d(Globals.tag, "connection opened!");
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            Log.d(Globals.tag, "input stream captured");
            output = readStream(in);
            Log.d(Globals.tag, "stream read");
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d(Globals.tag, (e.getMessage() == null ? "IO Exception" : "IO : " + e.getMessage()));
        }

        finally
        {
            return output;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String json)
    {
        Log.d(Globals.tag, "Json response: " + json);
    }
}

private String readStream(InputStream in) throws IOException
{
    Log.d(Globals.tag, "entering readStream");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    String output = line;

    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        output += line;

    return output;
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

I have the android.permission.INTERNET line in there, but I'm not positive it's in the correct location.  May cause issues?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.northstar.minimap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:name="com.northstar.minimap.Globals"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.northstar.minimap.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.northstar.minimap.MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map"
            android:parentActivityName="com.northstar.minimap.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.northstar.minimap.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Output**

Logcat yields the following lines:

```
12-01 21:31:44.727    2188-2188/com.northstar.minimap D/Minimap﹕ >> getting maps json from http://httpbin.org/ip/
12-01 21:31:44.727    2188-2232/com.northstar.minimap D/Minimap﹕ connection opened!
12-01 21:31:45.106    2188-2232/com.northstar.minimap D/Minimap﹕ IO: http://httpbin.org/ip/
12-01 21:31:45.106    2188-2188/com.northstar.minimap D/Minimap﹕ Json response:
```

Basically, something's causing an IOException, and I'm not sure what - the exception's getMessage isn't exactly verbose.  Do I have to do any configuration for the emulator (JellyBean, API level 17)?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out this tutorial on reading from an HttpUrlConnection inputStream, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Comment: Have you tried it on a real device -do you get the same error?

Comment: @Selecsosi Just tried the lines used in that link; same exception.  Also, the writing method described there doesn't look particularly REST-friendly (multiple Android+REST tutorials pointed to the methods I'm currently using).

Comment: @Mike I haven't yet; my Galaxy Nexus needs an as-of-yet unreleased update for this API level.  I'll have a Nexus 7 (2013) in a few weeks, but in the mean time, I'm stuck with the emulator.